# Weird little flap on the side of a Canon EOS Rebel T6?

Tags: canon

I have been an owner of a Canon EOS Rebel T6 for around 3 years now, and now I've gotten around to looking into a peculiar thing. On the side of my camera, I see this little tiny black flap, (opposite side of the 3 ports (hmdi, trigger, usb) and I opened it up to reveal a small black square hole. I looked in the manual and it said it's a DC Power jack. I cannot find these power cables anywhere on amazon or elsewhere. Am I correct?

Comment: Probably helpful if you post a photo of the thing you're talking aboutl.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's all covered in your [*EOS Rebel T6/EOS 1300D Instruction Manual*](http://gdlp01.c-wss.com/gds/8/0300022698/01/eos-rebelt6-1300d-im-en.pdf).

From page 27 we see that it is called the *DC Cord Hole*.

[image]

From page 270 we see than it is a port that allows a wire from a transformer to provide power to the camera via a *DC Coupler* that is shaped like a battery with contacts in the appropriate places that is inserted into the caemra's battery chamber.

[image]

In addition to the fairly expensive Canon branded DC Couplers and transformers, there are also cheaper third party products available that are clones of the Canon units. Just as with third party batteries, use them at your own risk, but if you buy a third party brand with a reputation for quality from a reputable seller, you're probably no more likely to have any issues tan if you buy a genuine Canon unit. Also be aware of the existence of counterfeit Canon-branded products sold by unscrupulous dealers (including third party sellers on amazon - and forget anyone on eBay).

Canon and/or their authorized retailers don't seem to place a priority in keeping them in stock, probably because they're so ridiculously expensive that they don't sell that many. Third party knock-offs are far easier to find [on amazon](https://www.amazon.com/s?k=Canon%20ACK-E10).

Comment: Wow... I was stupid and thought that was an external battery charger at first until I saw the picture you posted.

Answer (score 1):

In Canon DSLRs, there is a small rubber flap near the hinge of the battery compartment. This flap covers a hole where the wire goes out when you use a [DC coupler](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07H2B57JG) so that you can still close the battery door with the adapter inside.

Comment: Go to Best Buy or another store with cameras on display to see DC couplers in action.